# Socket I/O problems using a platform independent thread handler in c

Tags: c, sockets

I try to create a socket server that should work on both, linux and windows in the same way. When the server runs on windows it works as expected.

But i have problems reading and writing to a client socket **in linux**. The client connects correctly and also the thread is created but the communication doesnt work. So it might be an error inside the thread handler function. Here is the example code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>

#ifdef _WIN32 /* Windows */
#include <winsock.h>
#include <io.h>
#else /* UNIX/Linux */
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

#define RCVBUFSIZE 1024

/**
 * Thread Handler
 */
#ifdef _WIN32
DWORD WINAPI process_thread(LPVOID lpParam) {
    SOCKET current_client = (SOCKET)lpParam;
#else
void process_thread(int sock) {
    int current_client = sock;
#endif
    printf("[***] thread spawned\n");
    char buf[1024];
    int res;       
    while(1) {       
        res = recv(current_client, buf, 1024, 0);           
        if(res>0) {
            buf[res] = '\0';
            send(current_client, buf, strlen(buf), 0);
        }       
    }    
}

/**
 * Main
 */
int main( int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int port = port = atoi(argv[1]);

    struct sockaddr_in server, client;

    #ifdef _WIN32
    SOCKET sock, fd;
    #else
    int sock, fd;
    #endif

    unsigned int len;

    #ifdef _WIN32
    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(0x102,&wsaData);
    #endif

    memset( &server, 0, sizeof (server));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server.sin_port = htons(port);

    sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof( server));
    listen(sock, 5);

    #ifdef _WIN32
        DWORD thread;
    #else
        pthread_t thread;
    #endif

    while(1) {
        len = sizeof(client);
        fd = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&client, &len);
        if(fd>0) {
            printf("[***] new client connected\n");
            #ifdef _WIN32
            CreateThread(NULL, 0, process_thread, (LPVOID)fd, 0, &thread);
            #else
            pthread_create( &thread , NULL , process_thread , (void*) &client);
            #endif
        }
    }

    #ifdef _WIN32
    closesocket(fd);
    #else
    close(fd);
    #endif

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I suggest using a library.  [libae](https://github.com/aisk/libae) was fun to learn and has a working example server.  I studied sockets by playing around with this code.  You'll find there are a lot of little gotchas that the library owners already ran into and fixed.

Comment: I will look at this but i will first get a working thread without a library. I think i am not so far of it..

Comment: You're passing the thread &client (which is the ADDRESS of the client) but then you're treating it like a file descriptor in the function.

Comment: Thank you very much, you should make it an answer, it solves the problem.. I pass `(int) fd` now.